# Network icon disappeared

Tags: network-manager

I started my pc and just saw that the network icon was disappeared, searched for solutions and restarted network manager but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

One way of bringing the networking back without losing your current login session is to restart your router by pushing the power button which is usually located in the back of the router.  Wait 10 seconds after you stop the router and then push the power button again to restart it.

Restarting GNOME shell will often bring back missing desktop and panel icons without even needing to log out. Restarting GNOME shell does not close any of your applications, and if a web browser is open it stays open with all its tabs after restarting GNOME shell.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, and then type `r` in the pop-up Run a Command window and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to restart GNOME Shell  without interfering with any already opened windows.

Alternatively you can restart the GNOME shell without interfering with any already opened windows by replacing the running window manager, and the missing Panel icons will reappear.

```
setsid gnome-shell --replace
```

Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> again before you close the terminal.